# Install Java in Debian server

Tags: debian, java, apt

I am trying to install Java (JRE) on Debian. When I run the following apt-get command:

```
apt-get install sun-java5-bin sun-java5-jre unixodbc libasound2 java-common locales libltdl3 odbcinst1debian1
```

installation brings up a graphic prompt in my shell terminal asking to agree to terms of use.
I press down to scroll through the terms but **I cannot press OK**, i tried clicking on it and pressing enter but nothing worked.

Is there a way to make sure apt-get only brings up console installations or is there another way to install java?

[image: Terminal]

Comment: That ain't a GUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press the [Tab] key to advance to the Ok button, then press [Enter].  All of the debian text dialogs function in this manner.

Comment: That was easy...